# How to scroll through form records when focus is on subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have two subforms within a form: ItemNumberSubform and ItemDetailSubform within OrderNumberForm.

ItemNumberSubform has navigation buttons that the user can scroll through the records.
However, the user wants to use the scroll wheel to navigate the records in the ItemNumberSubform when they are editing the content in ItemDetailSubform . When they scroll in ItemDetailSubform while editing it will change the record in ItemNumberSubform and ItemDetailSubform to the next record.

```
Forms![OrderNumberForm]![ItemNumberSubform]
Forms![OrderNumberForm]![ItemDetailSubform]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Mouse Wheel event of the subform, very roughly:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal Page As Boolean, ByVal Count As Long)
    Me.Parent.Recordset.Move Count
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it does not seem to reference properly to [ItemNumberSubform]. Thanks.

Comment: @Bruno Your edit has changed the whole approach in that you are looking to synchronise a second subform from a first subform, as far as I understand. Have a look at the Customer Orders form in the Northwind Sample database (NWind), which does what you want to a certain extent. I do not believe you can synchronise successfully with the mouse wheel, only with the selection of a record.